# Store not updating in IE11 (react redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, internet-explorer-11

in IE 11 I can't update my store.
First time it add data, but next time, when I try update it not working.

I try use polyfill

```
import Immutable from 'immutable'
const objectAssign = require('object-assign');
const initialUserState =
{

}
;
const BackupReducer = function(state = initialUserState, action) {
   //console.log('actiondata in reducer:' + action.data + action.type);

  switch(action.type) {

  case 'GET_BACK_LIST':
         return objectAssign({}, state, { backups: action.data });
 break;
```

but it not helps:
in console I see:

[image]

Comment: Is it not working only in IE11

Comment: yes... only in IE

Comment: Store code looks ok, and providing that you confirmed the state is definitely updating to what you expect it to be then we'd have to see the component which isn't updating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in axios. it caching data, so I just add param in header

```
Pragma: 'no-cache'
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once! I have been having the same problem...

Comment: Where we need to add this cache in the file? @JohnnyDerp